# Django/Python How should this cronjob be executed

Tags: python, django, apache2, cron

I created a simple python script that allows me to update a chosen animal to be displayed on the sites frontpage.

when I am in my ssh, I run it like this.

```
cd /www/site/mydirectory
python perform_daily_action.py
```

How do I run this in my crontab as a cronjob.

I tried to do

```
30    09    *    *    *    cd /www/site/mydirectory;python perform_daily_action.py
```

Although this does not seem to work.

Suggestions?

Comment: Does the python script not run at all, or does the Python script misbehave because the working directory is wrong? Can you see anything in /var/log/syslog? Does it work if you put the two lines in a shell script and have cron execute that?

Comment: No, didn't run at all. @Flow came up with an easy solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use this instead

```
30    09    *    *    *    python /www/site/mydirectory/perform_daily_action.py
```

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are great, I would only suggest using full path also for `Python` interpreter, because `cron` environment might be different than the regular one and also at some point you might want to switch to `virtualenv` and then you will definitely need `Python` interpreter from `virtualenv` folder.

Answer (score 1):

You must provide the full python location (for example /usr/bin/python) and/or perhaps give your machine some guidelines about your $PYTHONPATH. Try this:

```
30    09    *    *    * export PYTHONPATH=/www/site/mydirectory:.:$PYTHONPATH && /usr/bin/python /www/site/mydirectory/perform_daily_action.py
```